# Xen domain windows 2012 r2 - cant add usb

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, centos6, xen, windows-server-2016

I have xen 4.4.3-9.el6 on CentOS: 6.7 (Final)
Problem is I cant add usb devices to my windows 2012R2 domain;

If I use`xm usb-add demo_win2012_r2 host:0529:0620`: 
I can see my device in windows but it is not recognised. And it only works with usb flashdrives. Windows doesnt show any other device added this way.

After that I tried:

```
xm usb-hc-create demo_win2012_r2 2 4
xm usb-list demo_win2012_r2
WARNING: xend/xm is deprecated. 
Idx BE  state usb-ver  BE-path 
0   0   1     USB2.0  /local/domain/0/backend/vusb/4/0 
port 1: 
port 2: 
port 3: 
port 4:
```

List of my devices:

```
xm usb-list-assignable-devices
WARNING: xend/xm is deprecated.
2-2          : ID 0951:1666 Kingston DataTraveler 3.0
3-1          : ID 0b38:0003 VIRTUAL USB MULTIMEDIA KEYBOARD
4-1          : ID 0529:0620 Aladdin Token JC
```

When I trie:

```
xm usb-attach  demo_win2012_r2 0 1 2-2
WARNING: xend/xm is deprecated.
Unexpected error: <class 'xen.util.vusb_util.UsbDeviceParseError'>
Please report to xen-devel@lists.xen.org
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/sbin/xm", line 20, in <module>
main.main(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xm/main.py", line 3946, in main
_, rc = _run_cmd(cmd, cmd_name, args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xm/main.py", line 3970, in _run_cmd
return True, cmd(args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/xm/main.py", line 3011, in xm_usb_attach
if vusb_util.bus_is_assigned(bus):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/util/vusb_util.py", line 275, in bus_is_assigned
raise UsbDeviceParseError("Can't get assignment status: (%s)." % bus)
xen.util.vusb_util.UsbDeviceParseError: vusb: Error parsing USB device info: Can't get assignment status: (2-2).
```

The same with other devices. Ofcourse I hav installed gplpv drivers on my windows.

When I create Virtual usb host controller with `usb-hc-create` Windows recognizes it only as XenPVUSB Device driver.

I have tried: `xm usb-add demo_win2012_r2 host:0951:1666` 
In this case Usb flash drive is visible in windows domain Device manager as unrecognised device with error code 10 and other usb devices isn't visible at all.

What am I missing?

Edit:
Also tried windows server2016 and clean windows 2012 R2 install So I gues issue is on windows side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From xen-devel@lists.xen.org

This could possibly be a side-effect of having no PVUSB backend; it
could also be a straight-up bug in xend.

If it's an issue with having no PVUSB backend, you could try to build a
kernel with support; the SLES kernel is probably your best bet, as I
*think* they officially support it.

If you have PVUSB available, then it's probably a bug in xend.
Unfortunately xend has been poorly maintained for some time. Xen 4.4 is
already out of support, and xend was removed from the tree shortly after
the Xen 4.5 development window opened (hence the warnings).  So in this
case it would most likely be classified as WONTFIX.

PVUSB support for xl is 99% certain to be available for Xen 4.7.